# Auto-Set Run64BitRuntime for different packages when debugging?

Tags: excel, debugging, ssis

I was wondering if anyone knows how to automatically set Run64BitRuntime to 'false' when loading specific packages for debugging purposes, leaving it 'as is' for all the rest?

I have one package in particular that writes out to an Excel workbook, containing multiple worksheets. We're migrating from VS2012 to VS2013 to line things up and now that I can't use CozyRoc's stuff (sniff) for Excel to take away my pain :) and after an afternoon of revisiting SSIS Excel hell. I keep forgetting to set the debug value to false and given that I am about to turn the package over to another fellow (who is bright and gets it) I'd REALLY like to ease the pain going forward unless/until there is a better approach.

So, any better approaches -or- does anyone know how to auto-switch Run64BitRuntime to false when a package is opened?

Thanks!

Comment: The Run64BitRuntime is a project level setting, so there is no way to set it per package.  You might put all your 32bit packages into their own project, but that would probably not make much organizational sense.  :(  Alternatively, if you run the packages from a master package, you could have it call the 32bit version of dtexec in a execute process task and execute the 32 bit packages as a child package.

Comment: Mark, Apologies for the tardy reply. Thank you for your comment. I had hoped... [smile] Fortunately there is only this one package. (at this point) to be aware of this issue.

Many thanks!

Doug